# An attempt to get a variant of Agoh–Giuga conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, divisors-multiples, congruences

The idea of this post is an attempt to explore a variant of the so-called Agoh–Giuga conjecture. In past days, and today, I tried to think about variants of this conjecture exploring congruences about the denominators of Gregory coefficients (because I have persuaded myself that it is possible to get congruences from this sequence to get an equivalent form of Agoh–Giuga conjecture), and also thinking a variant using the so-called radical of an integer $\operatorname{rad}(m)$ but both attempts were failed.

In this post I present a conjecture, maybe miscellany, or maybe you can find easily a counterexample, but I tried to get the best conjectures. See also the conjectures in first comments. My conjecture is similar than the equivalent form that shows the Wikipedia section [*Equivalent formulation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoh%E2%80%93Giuga_conjecture#Equivalent_formulation) from the article *Agoh–Giuga conjecture*.

I go for it. For integers $m\geq 1$ we denote the sum of divisors function $\sum_{1\leq d\mid m}d$ as $\sigma(m)$, that is an important number theoretic function (in particular is a multiplicative function).

**Fact.** If $n$ is a prime number, then Fermat's little theorem implies that  $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^{\sigma(n)-2}\equiv -1\text{ mod }n$$
holds.

> **Question.** A) Prove or refute the following conjecture:
>
> *If* $n>1$ *is an integer satisfiying*  $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^{\sigma(n)-2}\equiv -1\text{ mod }n\tag{C}$$
>   *then* $n$ *is a prime number*.
>
> I've tested it for $2\leq n\leq 4000$. In case that it is difficult to find a counterexample, it is welcome if you want to add what work can be done or what  heuristic can be useful to check the veracity of this conjecture.
>
> B) In case that it is difficult to find a counterexample, can you find an equivalent form of the conjecture $(C)$, thus following a thread of mathematical reasoning from my conjecture $(C)$ as a starting point? **Many thanks.**

I can not to find a counterexample with my computer program.

I hope that there aren't typos in my calculations with my computer, and also that the other examples that I add in commments as illustration of my exploration of other conjetures are interesting.

Comment: Let $\varphi(n)$ the Euler's totient function, I've tested in the segment of integers $2\leq n\leq 4000$ this conjecture: *The only composite integer satisfying*  $$\sum_{k=1}^{\sigma(n)-2}k^{n-1}\equiv \varphi(n)\text{ mod }(\sigma(n)-1)$$
*is* $n=517$.

Comment: Similarly one has the conjecture that I've tested for the same segment of integers: *If* $n\geq 2$ *is an integer satisfying the congruence* 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\varphi(n)}k^{n-1}\equiv \varphi(n)\text{ mod }(\varphi(n)+1)$$ *then* $n$ *is a prime number.*

Comment: Just a remark: working in the field $K:=\mathbb{Z}/p$ and denoting by $\sigma$ the Frobenius endomorphism, the sum in Agoh-Giuga conjecture becomes $\sum_{k\in K^{\times}}\dfrac{\sigma(k)}{k}=\sum_{k\in K^{\times}}\dfrac{k}{k}=p-1\equiv -1\mod p$. So one should find an endomorphism of a ring $R=\mathbb{Z}/n$ and show it is the Frobenius endomorphism of a field, entailing $n$ is prime. Maybe a proof akin to the one of Wilson's theorem can be reached.

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution @SylvainJULIEN

Comment: (1/2) This morning I tried to create a follow up of my question, it is just a draft of my thinking. Feel free if you want to study the problem that I evoke, it is as a present for your attention, but as I said it is just a draft, thus I don't know if the formula that I evoke is possible. I can see from Google Books the formula which I was inspired in page 89, due to Capelli, that is the great book by Eugene Dickson, *History of the Theory of Numbers*, Volume I: Divisivility and Primality, Dover Publications (2005).

Comment: (2/2) You can see the code written in Wolfram Language, that is a line in Wolfram Alpha online calculator and compare to the mentioned book @SylvainJULIEN . That is `(6^(sigma(7)-2)+7^(sigma(6)-2)-1)-(6*7)(IntegerPart(6^(sigma(7)-3)/7)+IntegerPart(7^(sigma(6)-3)/6)+1)`